# Inductive limit of manifolds?

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, category-theory

The inductive limit of a direct system of manifolds is a topological space (which I don't think needs be a manifold). But it seems like it should retain some of the structure of manifolds : for example, to a point $x$ in the limit you can associate the limit of the tangent planes, which is still a vector space.

Have those questions been studied, and if so does someone have a reference ? I would be especially interested in some remaining structure sufficient to do some differential calculus, kind of like orbifolds (which generalize manifolds in some sense, allowing some pathologies).

Comment: You could look at the category of ind-manifolds and do everything formally, instead of trying to realise it as a topological space or such.

Comment: This sort of construction comes up when trying to build explicit models for classifying spaces, such as $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$.  But in such cases one generally only cares about the homotopy theory or cohomology; I can't think of a reason why one would want to do calculus.

Comment: well in my case I have differentiable maps $\phi_n : M_n \rightarrow N$, where $M_n$ and $N$ are manifolds, and $\psi_n : M_n \rightarrow M_{n+1}$ are diffeomorphisms, and I want to say something "at the limit" about the maps $\phi_n$. I can probably work it out by hand, but I was wondering if there is an already existing theory for handling such situations

Comment: People study many interesting generalizations of manifolds, and I wouldn't be surprised if ind-manifolds were included in some of these: see, for example, http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+smooth+space .

Comment: thanks for your comments, I'll go read about ind-manifolds and the stuff in Quiaochu Yuan's link !